# Can I use Firebase Storage for online music streaming?

Tags: android, firebase, audio-streaming, firebase-storage

What I want is to save mp3 files on Firebase Storage and then stream it to an Android device. All the tutorials on [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) discuss about the image file upload and download.

If there are any other cloud that is more easy than Firebase to store and stream audio for android, then please suggest.

Comment: at least you should try it first, and in case you have problem you can ask in SO. here for start you can upload any file in GC storage. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files to play/stream music you can use https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer

Comment: We've got a streaming download API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StreamDownloadTask

Answer (score 33):

1. Firebase provide **StreamDownloadTask** as Mike has suggested, for getting **InputStream**
   but unfortunately *MediaPlayer* doesn't accept a direct stream. Now
   we have 2 options if we strictly like to continue with InputStream, as far as I know -

   a. Write a stream in the *temporary file* and pass it to the media player. Personally, *I don't recommend* this approach. It includes **unnecessary data writing** and you also have to maintain *synchronization* between streamed data, file writing and media play.

   b. Create **StreamProxy** server as npr news App doing. You can find the source code of App [here](https://github.com/unofficial/npr-android-app).
2. Simple way to play Music file from Firebase is to first fetch the *download URL* by using *storage reference* and pass that URL to media player as a dataSource. Below is the **code snippet** -

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

           private MediaPlayer mMediaplayer;

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
               mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
               mMediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
               fetchAudioUrlFromFirebase();
           }

           private void fetchAudioUrlFromFirebase() {
               final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
               // Create a storage reference from our app
               StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("PATH_OF_YOUR_AUDIO_FILE");
               storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                       try {
                           // Download url of file
                           final String url = uri.toString();
                           mMediaplayer.setDataSource(url);
                           // wait for media player to get prepare
                           mMediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(MainActivity.this);
                           mMediaplayer.prepareAsync();
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }

                   }
               })
                       .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                               Log.i("TAG", e.getMessage());
                           }
                       });

           }

           @Override
           public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
               mp.start();
           }
       }
   ```