# how can I play my audio files in a listView from firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter

I have gone through google links and all I have been able to gather is on how I can play audio from firebase on a button click. In my App I have added custom buttons on my listView item. I have tried to play my files from the raw folder but this will increase the Apk size which I am avoiding.

I am trying to make the buttons in my adapter class play different audio urls on click.

Please does anyone know how I can I play my audio files in a listView from firebase storage?

I want to make the buttons play in order, just as it in my firebase database.
 This [Can I use Firebase Storage for online music streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764165/can-i-use-firebase-storage-for-online-music-streaming)  Only gives explanation on how to play with One url.
What about using muiltiple Urls from firebase taking each item on the listView???

Here is my **AudioActivity**

```
public class AudioActivity extends Activity{

    private ArrayList<AudiosModel> arrayList;
    private CustomAudioAdapter adapter;
    private ListView songList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.songs_list);

        songList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songList);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(new AudiosModel("", "",));
        arrayList.add(new AudiosModel("", "", ));
        arrayList.add(new AudiosModel("", "", ));
        arrayList.add(new AudiosModel("Success Defined", "", R.raw.tan));
        arrayList.add(new AudiosModel("", "", R.raw.tan));
        arrayList.add(new AudiosModel("", "", R.raw.tan));
        arrayList.add(new AudiosModel("", "", R.raw.tan));
        arrayList.add(new AudiosModel("Divine Friends", "", R.raw.tan));
        arrayList.add(new AudiosModel("Time", "", R.raw.tan));

        adapter = new CustomAudioAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_music_item, arrayList);
        songList.setAdapter(adapter);
             }
     }
```

and here is my Adapter Class

```
public class CustomAudioAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList<AudiosModel> arrayList;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Boolean flag = true;

    public CustomAudioAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<AudiosModel> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName, txtSinger;
        ImageView ivPlay, ivStop;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongName);
            viewHolder.txtSinger = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Singer);
            viewHolder.ivPlay = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPlay);
            viewHolder.ivStop = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivStop);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final AudiosModel music = arrayList.get(position);

        viewHolder.txtName.setText(music.getName());
        viewHolder.txtSinger.setText(music.getSinger());

        // play music
        viewHolder.ivPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(flag){
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, music.getSong());
                    flag = false;
                }
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                }
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
}
```