# How can I persist Audio from firebase storage locally

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I created an Android app that can download and playback audio in firebase storage. But every time I have to play an audio, I need to download it over again. Is there a way to set persistence for audio files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should download & save it to local or you can try live streaming as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764165/can-i-use-firebase-storage-for-online-music-streaming/40327315

Comment: I can stream already from firebase storage using the url. If I would try saving it locally and playing from there. 